# Is this uncertainty representation correct?

Tags: time-series, gamma-distribution, uncertainty

I have a set of execution times for some processes. But there is uncertainty in these values. I call this $$ET + \lambda ET $$, where $\lambda ET$ is the delay. I sample $\lambda$ from a gamma distribution, which is always positive. For this gamma distribution, $\lambda$ is the mean and I choose appropriate scale (parameter).

Is there any specific name for this uncertainty representation? Are there any mistakes in it?

Comment: Any comments/criticism are welcome. Waiting!

Comment: No reply ? Do I need to be more clear or give more information?

Comment: No reply? Still waiting.